# Proper use of threads in using Java and Servlets

Tags: java, multithreading, war

I am pretty new in the whole Servlets area and I am trying to implement a method that will wait for an a time variable given by a user( e.g 1 minute)  and then it will start a countdown until the given time reaches 0. I thought the only way I can do that is by using Threads.
I am exporting my Java Project as a war , deploy it but when I import 1 minute the webpage does not prints anything until I reload it and If I go back using my browser the thread is still running.

The code below executes the thread.

Can you please suggest me whether I should use the asychronous threads (and maybe explain a little bit the difference with normal threads) or I can continue using the Thread as it is.

```
 if(minutes<=0) {
            out.println("<center><h3>Time cannot be negative</h3></center>");
     }
     else 
     {
         new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    out.println("<center><h3>Minutes :"+(minutes)+"</h3></center>");
                    Thread.sleep(minutes*60000);
                    out.println("<p align=\"CENTER\"> <a href=\"timer\">Return</a><br>");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                out.println("Interruption Found");

                }
            }
         }).start();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Well, no, you shouldn't use a thread. If you do, the servlet method returns, and the request-handling thread flushes and closes the response writer. I hope you're doing that only as an exercise.

Comment: @JBNizet Currently I am still doing it as an exercise but I would like to learn more on what is the best solution for this. Can you suggest something instead of using a thread in the doPost method?

Comment: You should avoid long-running operations like this, in general. You should also avoid creating new threads, and should rather use a shared ThreadPoolExecutor to avoid having too many concurrent threads and bringing the server to its knees. Send a request starting a background operation and return immediately. Then use AJAX polling, or server-sent events, or websockets to know what the status of the background job is (if necessary).

Comment: @JBNizet Ok. So inside my doPost instead of using a new thread I should using something like a Rest call?

Comment: Err, no. I said: "[you] should rather use a shared ThreadPoolExecutor to avoid having too many concurrent threads and bringing the server to its knees". What does that have to do with REST calls?

Comment: I mean is it better to completely leave the whole thread idea and go with REST etc? It might sounds completely idiotic but I am really really noob :P . The way I see it is I use my doPost method and if an event occurs (lets say the user pressed button 1 ) then a thread is running. What the alternative to this?

Comment: I have no idea of what you mean with "go with REST". I told you how I would solve a problem resembling the fake one you presented, i.e. start a long-running process and be able to know its status. If you have a different problem to solve, then ask another question explaining, precisely, what the problem is.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok Let's rephrase my question then. What will be your suggestion for a servlet that will expect a user input (Let's say an x amount of minutes ) and when the user inserts the minutes in the field the server should wait this amount, print a countdown and then exit when ready?

Comment: I don't see the point of doing that. There's no reason to block a request-handling thread, doing nothing, for several minutes. I have a hard time understanding the point of doing that, but if I really had to, I would probably do the whole wait + countdown completely on the frontend.

Comment: He it trying to implement some kind of "it happens after N seconds" behavior on the client (browser) side.  This is the wrong way to do it.  Aubin's answer hints at 2 of the 3 right ways ....

Comment: @JBNizet In my doPost I get the response. If an event is identified(e.g. the user pressed button 1 that tells him to start a countdown for 1 minute) then I open a tread and keep the connection open for 1 minute. Inside this period of time, the user might request more things than just a countdown but that's the simple implementation for now. Inside the thread.run I use the Thread.sleep for the requested amount of time. To sum up, I would like to have a method that will keep my connection alive and present a countdown to my front-end for the amount of minutes the user inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to answer the HTTP request, without delay. A thread isn't a solution for that.

You may use one of the following:

- Using some Ajax (client side controlled)
- WebSocket (server side controlled)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Should I continue using doPost and doGet methods?

Comment: @MikeS.  That's orthogonal.  And it depends on which of the suggested alternatives you use.  Understand the alternatives ...